# OS starts lagging about every 5 seconds with HDMI to VGA

Tags: display, high-sierra, hdmi, vga

Since I updated from Sierra to High Sierra I have an issue when i connect a second monitor to my macbook pro 15 inch 2017 (USB-C to HDMI -> HDMI to VGA). Namely, the OS starts lagging about every 5 seconds which makes it impossible to work with it.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/87168

The issue does not occur when booting in safe mode.
I tried resetting NVRAM and SMC.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: It is possible there is a glitch when using two adaptors connected together. There exist USB-C > VGA converters in the wild. Perhaps you can capture one and give it a try. [These adaptors](https://www.amazon.com/Apple-USB-C-VGA-Multiport-Adapter/dp/B00VU2NHVG) work best at my institution. We tried a few 3rd party adaptors, but these won out for compatibility and durability.

Comment: Doest "the OS starts lagging about every 5 seconds" not sound like a specific problem? To state the obvious, I would like a fix for this specific problem.

Comment: I understand what you wrote, but there's not enough to work with to give you a concrete answer. You give a link to a Apple forum post that has a tenuous connection to the problem you are experiencing. There's just not enough information about what _you've_ done to correct the problem. To augment my post, I have had painful experiences with computers and monitors connected through multiple adaptors, where a single adaptor solved the problem immediately. Q: When you detach the 2nd monitor and adaptors, does the computer work correctly without the lag? I've retracted the Close flag.

Comment: "When you detach the 2nd monitor and adaptors, does the computer work correctly without the lag?" - Yes

Comment: Well, that's certainly a telling trouble-shooting tip which points directly to the adaptors (and any cables) involved in connecting the monitor to the computer!